# Detect changes in collection of models by collection of DTOs

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have collection of some models:

```
class Person
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public int Age {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
}

var collectionModel = new List<Person>{ ... };
```

And Collection of DTOs:

```
class PersonDto
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public int Age {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public int RowNumber {get;set;}
}

var collectionDto = new List<PersonDto>{ ... };
```

So, `collectionModel` I get from repository (database), `collectionDto` I get from remote client.

Is there an effective way to compare these collections and "apply changes" (update changed entities, remove non-existing and add new) on `collectionModel` to save it in database?

An obvious option - compare collections "by hands", update properties, create and delete objects. But this code becomes repeating.

Comment: For updated entities you could write a IEqualityComparer that compares your db objects to your DTOs, then you have a list of those that you need to send back to the db as `EntitiyState.Modified`. Add and delete should be simple (add won't have primary IDs and deletes should be marked for deletion).

Comment: @Wurd thank you, but this is exactly what I mean saying "by hands"

Comment: If you are concerned about the mapping then you could look into AutoMapper. This will make conversion between your model and DTOs a one liner if the property names match. :) But as below answer, for the db logic you have to put some effort in.

Comment: Not sure that you can find this functionality 'out of the box' somewhere... Create your own class that does it, it's not that difficult. Use automapper, and IEqualityComparer. Take a look at [GraphDiff](http://blog.brentmckendrick.com/introducing-graphdiff-for-entity-framework-code-first-allowing-automated-updates-of-a-graph-of-detached-entities/) library.

Comment: @Wurd we have something like this now, I try to find all possible options. Anyway, thank you for your opinion, it will help me to make a desicion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is not. If you want to avoid manual mapping of properties, you could pass Person as DTO and then attach it to the entity framework context. In your repository:

```
protected virtual void Merge(object modified, object attached)
{
    if (attached != modified)
        DB.Entry(attached).CurrentValues.SetValues(modified);
    else
        DB.Entry(modified).State = EntityState.Modified;
}
```

and then on insert or update:

```
public void UpdateSomething(Something obj)
{
    var attached = DB.Somethings.Single(x => x.ID == obj.ID);

    Merge(obj, attached);
    DB.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, I will think about this option

Comment: @Backs in merge the object attached should it be the same type of entity ? Here its 1 is dto and other is entity model

Comment: @Eldho at first I get DTOs, but I can convert them in model